# SQL Server stored procedure starts new instance before previous instance finishes

Tags: sql-server, transactions

The scenario: I have a stored procedure that creates a Help Desk Ticket (`CreateTicket`) which calls another stored procedure that should get the next available service representative (`GetNextRep`).

I'm running SQL Server 2017.

`GetNextRep` is doing a round robin of available reps. Let's say only 2 people are working (Rep1 and Rep2).

`GetNextRep` looks at a column `LastAssignedDate` in the `Rep` table indicating the last time they were assigned a ticket. The oldest datetime stamp gets the next ticket.

So a ticket comes in and Rep1 was assign most recently, so the ticket is assigned to Rep2 and updates Rep2's `LastAssignedDate`.

The second ticket gets assigned to Rep1, because Rep2 was assigned the last ticket.

No one gets assigned 2 tickets in a row.

If I call `CreateTicket` in SQL Server, this works fine. I hit F5 over and over, and it round robins between all the Service Reps.

I created a loop to call `CreateTicket` however many times I want. In that case, `GetNextRep` assigns every ticket to the same rep, which I do not want.

I think the first call to `CreateTicket` is still running when the subsequent stored procedure calls are made. So `LastAssignedDate` isn't getting updated before the next stored procedure call.

Hope this question is clear. I wonder if anyone has any troubleshooting tips?

Comment: "I think the first call to CreateTicket is still running when the subsequent stored procedure calls are made." if the loop is in TSQL, that is not happening.  You have a bug in your code.  Try to simplify it to the point you can post it here.  Doing that you'll either figure it out yourself, or someone here can then take a look.

Comment: You should probably show us the stored procedure code, or a generic version of it, if you want specific guidance. And the DDL for the queue table (and its indexes). Generally speaking queue reading procs should be transactional and when selecting from the queue table they need to use `ROWLOCK`, `UPDLOCK` and `READPAST` [hints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/hints-transact-sql-table) so that each queue item is only processed by a single proc call. Index design on queue tables needs to be deliberate as things like a clustered index on identity(1,1) columns is... not ideal.

Comment: Please show code. We can't answer otherwise